# Number of ways to write $2n-1$ as $4x+2y+4xy+1$ where $x$ and $y$ are nonnegative integers

Tags: number-theory, multiplicative-function

I see a claim in [OEIS/A1227](https://oeis.org/A001227) which state that

"Number of ways to write $2n-1$ as $4x+2y+4xy+1$ where $x$ and $y$ are nonnegative integers equals number of odd divisors of $n$."

I can't see how the representation number relate to the odd divisor function. Any comments and links is appreciated.

Comment: Did you see the references given at OEIS there? For example, Mircea Merca, Combinatorial interpretations of a recent convolution for the number of divisors of a positive integer, Journal of Number Theory, Volume 160, March 2016, Pages 60-75, function tau_o(n).

Comment: May be helpful to note: If $4x + 2y + 4xy + 1 = 2n - 1$, then $(2x + 1) (2y + 2) = 2n$ so $(2x + 1) (y + 1) = n$.

Comment: Per the comment of @DanielSchepler, there is a 1-1 relationship between each odd divisor of $(n)$, and each solution of the form $(2x+1)(y+1) = n.$  Any candidate values of $(x,y)$ will form a solution if and only if $(2x +1)$ is a divisor of $(n)$.  However, any divisor of $(n)$ of form $(2x +1)$ must be an odd number.

Comment: Thanks for all useful comments!! @ Dietrich Burde ; Daniel Schepler ; user2661923.